# BufferBlock<T> Class (off)loading to/from persistent repo

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, persistence, tpl-dataflow

I have a question concerning BufferBlock offloading to persistent repo in c#.

If I have understood correctly, BufferBlock keeps all messages in memory. 
Now I want to prevent the loss of these messages in case of burst-modes, crashes or program shutdown.

Is it possible (without custom implementation) to offload/backup all pending messages in a persistent repo so they can be loaded in the BufferBlock later on?

Comment: TPL Dataflow doesn't provide any persistent storage implementation OOTB. It's meant to be an in memory data pipeline solution. If you want persistence, you can first load all data to the persistent storage and look that data to the `BufferBlock`.

Comment: TPL Dataflow implements ... dataflows, not workflows with persistent steps. Dataflows are one of many models for concurrent/parallel processing so storage really isn't applicable to them

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing like that in TPL Dataflow itself, and I'm not aware of any other library that would offer dataflow blocks that do this.

Comment: Emphasis on "any other library", regardless of language or OS.